# Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ with Galois group $D_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ be given, where $i^2=-1$. I want to know:

> Whether there is a Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}(i)$ such that $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}(i))\cong D_8$, where $D_8$ is the dihedral group of size 8?

I know the Fundamental Theorem of Galois theory, and how to calculate Galois groups.

I tried several guesses, such as $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4},i)$, $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/8},i)$, but none worked.

Comment: Take a dihedral extension of the rationals not containing i and lift it.

Comment: But @franzlemmermeyer, all the examples of extensions with group $D_8$ that we see in basic Galois Theory classes are $\Bbb Q(m^{1/4},i)$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I'm trying to prove $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{3-\sqrt{2}})/\mathbb{Q}$ has Galois group $D_8$

Comment: Nevermind, I found one. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+5\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{3-5\sqrt{2}})/\mathbb{Q}$, the splitting field of $x^4-6x^2-41$.

Comment: um... what's wrong with $\Bbb Q(2^{1/4}, i)$ ??

Comment: @mercio It cannot be lifted with $i$, since it already contains $i$.

Comment: but isn't it a Galois extension of $\Bbb Q(i)$ such that $Gal(K/\Bbb Q) = D_8$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo.

Comment: Starting from Q(i), build a biquadratic extension K/Q(i) and use a general procedure (see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1650320/300700) to embed K into an overextension L/Q(i) with Galois group $D_8$.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to know whether one exists, not what it is, so no need to guess at what an actual extension would be.

Instead, you could think only about the Galois groups. You can use the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory to show that such an extension exists if and only if there exists a group $G$ such that $G\cong D_8$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}(i))$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. If you show that, and find such a group (up to isomorphism), then you're done.

Why a normal subgroup in particular? Well, it has to be a Galois extension, not just any extension.